# How to take User Input in PL/sql Cursor FOR LOOP and update table based on the user input?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am taking the emp3 table which is same as emp table.

```
DECLARE 
  CURSOR incr_cur IS SELECT * FROM emp3 FOR UPDATE OF sal;
   v_job emp3.job%TYPE := '&ENTER_Job';
   v_cnt INTEGER;
BEGIN
 FOR r_l IN incr_cur LOOP
  IF v_job = r_l.job THEN
   UPDATE emp3 SET sal = sal + 100 WHERE CURRENT OF incr_cur;
  END IF;
 END LOOP;

FOR p_l IN incr_cur LOOP
IF v_job = p_l.job THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Salary of ' || p_l.ename || ' is: ' || p_l.sal || ' (Incremented).');
ELSE
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Salary of ' || p_l.ename || ' is: ' || p_l.sal || ' (Not Incremented).');
END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
```

After executing the script it will ask for user input.
I gave the INPUT 'CLERK' and the OUTPUT,
[image: Output]

But I want output like this,
[image: OutPUT1]

Comment: Please do not post images of text - just copy/paste the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just increment a variable after the `if` condition and then display it at the end.

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR ..
    ..
    v_cnt INTEGER;

    BEGIN
    ..
    ..
      FOR p_l in incr_cur  --second for loop
       LOOP
         IF v_job = p_l.job
          v_cnt := v_cnt + 1;
      ..
      END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Salary of '||v_cnt||' Employees are Incremented by 100');
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, It's Working Now.

Comment: The Table I've used contains 5 types of JOB : CLERK, SALESMAN, MANAGER, ANALYST and PRESIDENT. Suppose I Enter 'DEVELOPER' which is not a job category of the table, then How to display a Message, "THE Given Job is not listed."

Comment: Please Reply,The Table I've used contains 5 types of JOB : CLERK, SALESMAN, MANAGER, ANALYST and PRESIDENT. Suppose I Enter 'DEVELOPER' which is not a job category of the table, then How to display a Message, "THE Given Job is not listed."

Comment: @user5499820 : I suggest you to ask that as a separate question as this question answered your initial requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE 
CURSOR incr_cur IS SELECT * FROM emp3 FOR UPDATE OF sal;
v_job emp3.job%TYPE := '&ENTER_Job';
v_cnt INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
FOR r_l IN incr_cur LOOP
  IF v_job = r_l.job THEN
    UPDATE emp3 SET sal = sal + 100 WHERE CURRENT OF incr_cur;
  END IF;
END LOOP;

FOR p_l IN incr_cur LOOP
  IF v_job = p_l.job THEN
    v_cnt := v_cnt + 1;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Salary of ' || p_l.ename || ' is: ' || p_l.sal || ' (Incremented).');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Salary of ' || p_l.ename || ' is: ' || p_l.sal || ' (Not Incremented).');
  END IF;
END LOOP;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Salary of '|| v_cnt ||' Employees are Incremented by 100');
END;
```